# Select a record with multiple Condition

Tags: c#, .net

I have a datatable with two records in it.with following Command

```
DataRow maxRow = ds.Tables["EduPers"].Select("EduID = MAX(EduID)").SingleOrDefault();
```

which works fine, but this command which I need it, doesn't work

```
 st = "EduID = MAX(EduID) and EduId <" + MaxId;
 maxRow = ds.Tables["EduPers"].Select(st).SingleOrDefault();
```

which brings me null, it wrong , because it must fetch the second records.
what is wrong?
Thank you

Comment: The condition that you specify appears to be unsatifiable (to be sure you must tell what `MaxId` contains).

Comment: as @collapsar said, maybe you should change your condition.

Comment: Yep. Your condition is contradictionary. Also I recommend you to use EF + Linq to Entities for using such queries.

Comment: You must tell what is `MaxId` in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true condition and always is false! Max(EduId) is a unique number that given to EduId in first condition. on second condition you say that EduId should be less than an EduId! it's wrong. If your mean is getting EduId that is biggest in some EduIds that are smaller than a number you can do this:

```
st = "EduId <" + MaxId;
var rows = ds.Tables["EduPers"].Select(st).AsEnumerable();    
var maxRows = rows.Max(e => e.Field<int>("EduId"));
```

Comment: sure I did. but no success

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79950/discussion-between-siamak-ferdos-and-nnmmss).